# Why is my string undefined?

Tags: c++, permutation

The error says `s` is undefined at this point in my code:

```
cout << "Enter the string : ";

cin >> s;
```

How can I fix that?

Also, another error at my second bracket says "expecting a ;". What can I do to fix that?

Here's my full code:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <cctype>    
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    void permutation(string s, int i, int n)
    {
        int j;
        if (i == n)
            cout << s << "\t";
        else
        {
            for (j = i; j < s.length(); j++)
            {
                swap(s[i], s[j]);
                permutation(s, i + 1, n);
                swap(s[i], s[j]);

                cout << "Enter the string : ";
                cin >> s;
                cout << endl << "The permutations of the given string : " << endl;
                permutation(s, 0, s.length() - 1);
                cout << endl;
            }
```

Comment: Fix the *first* error first. You seem to be trying to declare a new function (`permutation`) inside your `main` function. That's the first thing you need to fix. Otherwise, the compiler gets terribly confused as soon as it sees the second `{` so you can't believe any errors that it finds after that.

Comment: Your code is completely broken, why `void permutation(string s, int i, int n)` is in `main`?

Comment: Code doesn't even compile.....

Comment: `main()` doesn't denote the main scope area of the module. In C/C++ `main()` is an entry point function. If you want to define a function, do it outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared your function inside the main block, which is causing the compilation error. Declare it outside as-

```
#include <cctype>    
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void permutation(string s, int i, int n)

{

int j;

if (i == n)

cout << s << "\t";

else

{

for (j = i; j < s.length(); j++)

{

swap(s[i], s[j]);

permutation(s, i + 1, n);

swap(s[i], s[j]);

}
}
}
int main()
{ 
 string s;
 cout << "Enter the string : ";

 cin >> s;

 cout << endl << "The permutations of the given string : " << endl;

 permutation(s, 0, s.length() - 1);

 cout << endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the place where you define the string s. C++ is declarative. You MUST declare all variables before using them. It's different from PHP, for instance, where initializing a variable is equivalent to declaring it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the nesting of your parenthesis as well. Looks like you have your permutation function declared inside of main().  That might confuse the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

void permutation(string s, int i, int n) is defined inside main . Place it outside and check . The following is wrong

```
int main()
{
void permutation(string s, int i, int n)
```